# Side-by-side Visual Studio 2015 Installs

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, installation

Kind of a strange question:

I use Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise for work, but I also teach courses and I feel using the Community Edition better suits my teaching since that's what the majority of my students have access to.

Does anybody know of a possible registry edit that would allow me to have both installed side-by-side on the same machine?

Many thanks!

Comment: Maybe you should (also) ask on [su]?